# react facebook share button does not work

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-share

share` libraryto use Facebook share button with react and this is the code

```
render(){
var url = `http://localhost:3000/${this.props.match.params.id}/${this.props.match.params.name}`
  return (
    {/*some other codes*/} 
    <FacebookShareButton url={url} quote={"გააზიარე"} className="share">
         <FacebookIcon size={32} round={true}/>
    </FacebookShareButton>
   )
}
```

but it does not work, I mean it opens facebook window but showing some error
about domain name, i think this problem is common, because i did everything according to documentation. what is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot share a `localhost` link, that link is only available on your own computer. Shared URLs need to be accessible by Facebook in public.

**UPDATE:**

Facebook shows an error message now saying "localhost won't work".

Comment: if it is public, yes, of course. make sure you understand why sharing localhost urls does not work.

Comment: if you explain it in more details, please

Comment: i am not sure what else to explain, to be honest. you just need to run your website on a public host, not on localhost...

Comment: that's what I meant in my first question. i meant heroku webserver or something like that

Comment: sure, some server like heroku, digitalocean, openshift, ..., it just needs to be available in public. localhost only lives on your own computer.